# The dbplyr package is installed and working on travis, why do I receive a message "there is no package called 'dbplyr'"?

Tags: r, dplyr, travis-ci, dbplyr

I'm testing an open source package called [eutradeflows](https://travis-ci.org/stix-global/eutradeflows/) on travis-ci. 
I placed the following instruction in [.travis.yml](https://github.com/stix-global/eutradeflows/blob/travis/.travis.yml) to install dbplyr:

```
r_packages:
  - dbplyr
```

I check that dbplyr works by calling one of its function with the following .travis.yml instruction:

```
  - Rscript -e "dplyr::check_dbplyr(); dbplyr::translate_sql(x +1)"
```

The `dbplyr::translate_sql` function does indeed return a result in travis see [build 268358848 line 1162](https://travis-ci.org/stix-global/eutradeflows/builds/268358848#L1162):

```
$ Rscript -e "dplyr::check_dbplyr(); dbplyr::translate_sql(x +1)"
<SQL> "x" + 1.0
```

But testthat tests that use other dbplyr functions inside my package complain, see [build 268358848 line 1292](https://travis-ci.org/stix-global/eutradeflows/builds/268358848#L1292):

```
"there is no package called 'dbplyr'"
```

The dbplyr is installed and working, how is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you add `dbplyr` to the DESCRIPTION file?

Comment: That [fixes it](https://travis-ci.org/stix-global/eutradeflows/builds/268385806) thanks! Should I delete the question?

Comment: @PaulRougieux No, it should be here in case someone else had the same issue.

Comment: @PaulRougieux Nice. I put that comment as an answer for people to see it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add package `dbplyr` to the DESCRIPTION file of your package.